# Game board printing

Tags: list, python-3.x, printing

I'm trying to print the board of my game with this funcion:

`board`is a list with the coordinates or cells occupated in the game

`lst` is a list with all the coordinates just to refer to.

```
def board_to_string(lst,board):
    for n in lst:
        for m in range(3):
            # it should be board[i]
            if n[m] in board[0]:
                n[m] = "o"
            else:
                n[m] = " "
    for lst2 in lst:
        print("---------------")
    print(str(lst2))

a = [['a1','b1','c1'],['a2','b2','c2'],['a3','b3','c3']]
b = [['b1','a3','a2'],['a2','g1']]
board_to_string(a,b)
```

Output is:

```
---------------
[' ', 'o', ' ']
---------------
['o', ' ', ' ']
---------------
['o', ' ', ' ']
```

There are two problems, I want it to search the coordinate in every sublist board has. I tried adding `for i in range(3)`but it prints twice and it doesn't work either.

The other problem is that I'm supposed to print a string but I can't think of a way to this, only with lists.

Comment: Someone? please

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
def board_to_string(lst,board):
    print("------")
    for n in lst:
        for m in range(3):
            # it should be board[i]
            if n[m] in board[0]:
                print("o", end="")
            elif n[m] in board[1]:
                print("x", end="")
            else:
                print(" ", end="")
            print("|", end="")
        print("\n------")

a = [['a1','b1','c1'],['a2','b2','c2'],['a3','b3','c3']]
b = [['b1','a3','a2'],['a1','c1']]
board_to_string(a,b)
```

Note that I corrected last but one row (list b), too